# CellUtil: Key type in createCell method

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am using the **CellUtil** class packaged in **org.apache.hadoop.hbase** to create a **Cell** object. The function header looks like this:

```
public static Cell createCell(byte[] row, byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, long timestamp, byte type, byte[] value)
```

What does the 5th. argument byte **type** represent? I looked into the KeyValueType class and it refers to an enum called Type with the following definition:

```
public static enum Type {
Minimum((byte)0),
Put((byte)4),

Delete((byte)8),
DeleteFamilyVersion((byte)10),
DeleteColumn((byte)12),
DeleteFamily((byte)14),

// Maximum is used when searching; you look from maximum on down.
Maximum((byte)255);

private final byte code;

Type(final byte c) {
  this.code = c;
}

public byte getCode() {
  return this.code;
}
```

My question is, what has the type minimum,  put, etc. got to do with the type of cell I want to create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarin, 
Please refer [69.7.6. KeyValue](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#keyvalue)

There are some scenarios in which you will use these enums. For Example, I'm writing coprocessor like below then I will use `KeyValue.Type.Put.getCode()`
similarly other Enums also can be used like this.
See example co-processor usage below...

```
package getObserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NavigableSet;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Cell;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.BaseRegionObserver;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.ObserverContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.RegionCoprocessorEnvironment;

public class Observer extends BaseRegionObserver{

    private boolean isOewc;

    @Override
    public void preGetOp(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> arg0,
            Get arg1, List<Cell> arg2) throws IOException {
        NavigableSet<byte[]> qset = arg1.getFamilyMap().get("colfam1".getBytes());
        if(qset==null){//do nothing

        }else{

            String message = "qset.size() = "+String.valueOf(qset.size());
            String m = "isOewc = "+String.valueOf(isOewc);
            this.isOewc = true;
            Cell cell = CellUtil.createCell(
                    "preGet Row".getBytes(), 
                    m.getBytes(), 
                    message.getBytes(), 
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                    KeyValue.Type.Put.getCode(), 
                    "preGet Value".getBytes());
            arg2.add(cell);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void postGetOp(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> arg0,
            Get arg1, List<Cell> arg2) throws IOException {
        String m = "isOewc = "+String.valueOf(isOewc);
        Cell cell = CellUtil.createCell(
                "postGet Row".getBytes(), 
                m.getBytes(), 
                "postGet Qualifier".getBytes(), 
                System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                KeyValue.Type.Put.getCode(), 
                "postGet Value".getBytes());
        arg2.add(cell);
    }
}
```

> Similarly other below [EnumTypes](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.Type.html#Put) can be used if you don't know which
>   operation you are going to perform on co-processor event..

[image]

[programcreek examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue&method=Type) clearly explains what is the usage of Put,Delete(prepare key value pairs for mutation) maximum,minimum (for range check). also Co-processor above example uses Put.

Comment: Can you lay out the usage of Put, Minimum, Maximum and Delete? Just a one liner would suffice.

Comment: Above code which was given is co-processor.  Co-processor works like a trigger. If that event arises, what needs to be done either Put, Delete or some thing else you can pass the enum. that's the usage.

Comment: Let me put it another way. Say I am writing a MR Unit test and I want to create a Cell using the CellUtil. Which of the above should I use and why.

Comment: regarding the usage of these enum Maximum and Minimum see this class how they used https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValueUtil.java

Comment: also for See examples how they have used http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue&method=Type

Comment: I have seen the above link on stack overflow before. The problem is that he is using a deprecated version of Result constructor. The answer I am looking for here is: Put is used when you want to do xyz, Delete is used when you want to do abc, etc. I have been over the KeyValueUtil classes, etc and couldn't find a satisfactory explanation. That is the reason behind posting this question. Thanks!

Comment: programcreek examples above clearly explains what is the usage of Put,Delete(prepare key value pairs for mutation) max,min (for range check). also Co-processor above example uses Put. Moreover you haven't mentioned Mr Unit test you are looking for...  I don't understand, what exactly you are looking for... so I would say all the best!

Comment: Can you move the above comment to the explanation?

Comment: added at bottom of the explanation.